# Meteor parent context within {{each}}

Tags: meteor

How do I access template variables within an `{{each}}` in Meteor?

For example,

```
<template name="test">
{{#if someValue}}It works!{{/if}}<br>
{{#each thing}}
    {{#if someValue}}It works in Each!{{/if}}<br>
{{/each}}
</template>
```

Expected behavior is to see "It works!" and "It works in Each!". `someValue` is not a property of any of the objects in the `thing` array.

My question is how to access the template scope from within the `{{each}}`?

Comment: I've discussed this type of issue in the UPDATE section of this answer of mine : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976634/context-inside-templates-with-iron-router/20977732#20977732 I hope it will help you.

Comment: @saimeunt I'm so confused by that but I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `..`, for example:

```
{{#each thing}}
    {{../this}}
    {{../fooField}}
{{/each}}
```

You can also use any of those as an argument to a helper.

Comment: I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work properly. I think this doesn't work within a `{{#if}}` specifically.

Comment: @ChristianStewart yes you're right, I remember this is a documented issue (can't find citation off the top of my head). But you can get around it by doing the `if` in a helper function instead of as a block helper.