# How do I access a meteor parent template data context inside #each?

Tags: meteor

Is there way to get access to the helpers of the parent template while I'm in an #each loop?

```
<template name="template2">
  {{test}}<br/>
  {{#each list}}
    {{this}}:{{../test}}<br/>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

The first {{test}} works, the one in the loop does not.  I've also tried {{../this.test}} unsuccessfully in case that was the answer.

Does the .. syntax not work here?  I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20976634/context-inside-templates-with-iron-router/20977732#20977732) answer, which seems to suggest that it does, but as you can see in this [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/Fvzqz7cy8ZvMniguA/DataContextTest) it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The title of the question indicates a parent-child relationship, however in the example there is only one template. Helpers are available to the whole template, so the context doesn't matter in this case. Just use `{{test}}` like this:

```html
<template name="template2">
  here:{{test}}<br/>
  {{#each list}}
    {{this}}:{{test}}<br/>
  {{/each}}
</template>
```

Comment: Ah... so simple.  I had assumed that the helpers followed the data context.  Thanks!